# Stream Analytics - Passing multiple, individual records within a window into a UDF

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I want to pass multiple, individual records within a set window (can be tumbling, hopping, sliding) without any aggregation into a javascript UDF like so:

Input data is:

```
{ "device":"A", "temp":20.0, "humidity":0.9, "param1": 83}
{ "device":"A", "temp":22.0, "humidity":0.9, "param1": 63}
{ "device":"B", "temp":15.0, "humidity":0.5, "param1": 13}
{ "device":"A", "temp":22.0, "humidity":0.5, "param1": 88}
{ "device":"A", "temp":22.0, "humidity":0.5, "param1": 88}
```

Pass records within a specified window as an object array:

```
function process_records(record_array) {
   //access individual records
   record_one_device = records[0].device
   record_two_device = records[1].device
   record_three_device = records[2].device
   ...
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Comment: Yup. Thanks a lot for the help Bruce :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement, I assumed that you could leverage the [Collect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt732314.aspx) aggregate function from Azure Stream Analytics. Here is my test, you could refer to it:

**Input**

```html
[  
    {
        "Make": "Honda",
        "Time": "2015-01-01T00:00:01.0000000Z",
        "Weight": 1000
    }, 
    {
        "Make": "Honda",
        "Time": "2015-01-01T00:00:03.0000000Z",
        "Weight": 3000
    },
    {
        "Make": "Honda",
        "Time": "2015-01-01T00:00:12.0000000Z",
        "Weight": 2000
    }, 
    {
        "Make": "Honda",
        "Time": "2015-01-01T00:00:52.0000000Z",
        "Weight": 1000
    }
]
```

With the following query, I could retrieve the data contained in temporal windows as follows:

```html
SELECT
    Make,
    System.TimeStamp AS Time,
    Collect() AS records
FROM
    Input TIMESTAMP BY Time
GROUP BY
    Make,
    HoppingWindow(second, 10,10)
```

[image]

Then, you could call `UDF.processRecords(Collect())` in your query. For more details, you could refer to [common Stream Analytics usage patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns) and [Azure Stream Analytics UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions) and [Stream Analytics Window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-window-functions).